# Null Parent field when lookup item is deleted

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say I have a parent table and a lookup table.  The parent table references the lookup table.  I want to be able to set the parent field to null if I delete the row from the lookup table that it references.

On delete or on cascade isnt working, or I am setting it wrong.  I don't want to delete the parent row just update the referenced field to null if I delete the item from the lookup table.

Comment: have you tried trigger?

Comment: Please add a [mre] to your question.

Comment: Please also refer to the ON DELETE SET NULL section of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-table-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: This is in db design, so there is no sql to share.  When I try Set Null i get errors.

Comment: Perhaps you might want to share your errors? Although, it might make answering the question easier

Answer (score 1):

Against my better judgment... I recommend using a "trigger".

When a delete occurs, "update" the other table.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16